# Java - How to get all the field names from JSON Schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

```
{
    "type": "TestType",
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "format": "date",
                "label": "field 1",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "field2": {
                "format": "date",
                "label": "field 2",
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [],
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

Hi Guys, I am new to JSON Schema, I just want to know how to define the Java model to mapping above JSON Schema, I want to get all the field name from the definition.

So it means that I want to parse the JSON Schema and return like this:

```
[field1, field2]
```

Note that the field list is automatic, may add more fields into the JSON Schema, field3, field4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.convert to `JSONObject`

2.save in `List`

3.convert `List` to `Array`

try this .

```
public void getKey(String response) {
    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject schema = jsonObject.getJSONObject("schema");
        JSONObject properties = schema.getJSONObject("properties");
        Iterator iterator = properties.keys();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next().toString();
            keyList.add(key);
        }
        String[] arr = (String[]) keyList.toArray(new String[keyList.size()]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: just a small thing, but you don't need to cast, because of the array (`new String[keyList.size()]`) you're providing

Comment: Thank for you suggestion.

Comment: Good luck to you.@Tony

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `json` is in a String variable named `var`.
use `org.json` for the below code.

```
JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject(var);
ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();

for (Object keyObj: jObj.keySet())
{
    String key = (String)keyObject;
    arr.add(key);        
}
```

That's it.

I have added maven dependency for `org.json` package for those who are working with maven!

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>  
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>  
    <version>20160810</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: OP will need to recurse/seek into the structure to otherwise find "field1" and "field2"

Comment: I think he only needs keys of objects inside `properties` .

Comment: what's var? that code will list all keys. is jObj already an instance of the schema? the OP has only the schema.

Comment: This is not exactly what OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

Recursive solution that will work with nested objects

```
public Set<String> getMetadataSchemaFields(JsonNode metadataSchema) {
    if (metadataSchema.has("properties")) {
        val fields = new HashSet<String>();
        metadataSchema.get("properties").fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
            val nodeFields = getMetadataSchemaFields(entry.getValue());
            if (nodeFields.isEmpty()) {
                fields.add(entry.getKey());
            } else {
                nodeFields.forEach(nodeField -> fields.add(entry.getKey() + "/" + nodeField));
            }
        });
        return fields;
    } else {
        return Set.of();
    }
}
```